# How to inspect a bull job in node.js using a debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging, bull

I'm using [nvim-dap](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-dap) to [debug](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started) my node.js app. If I set a breakpoint on function call directly it works just fine. However If I set a breakpoint on a job that is processed by [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull), and I run that job, the debugger fails to capture the breakpoint.

How do I run the command so that the debugger stops at a line of code in the job?

Comment: yes, @abbood  I believe that's a normal behavior for async calls. I believe bull dispatch an event for a job to be executed on a different thread of the request/response cycle.